# Iterate through geodataframes and overlay them to create a single output

Tags: geopandas

I am attempting to iterate through dissolved_result and overlay them using how='intersection' to create a single output file that represents all of the input dissolved_results. I am struggling with how best to do that, this is what I have so far and the error I get.

All inputs are polygons/multipolygons.

Edit: added some links to snaps to show what I'm trying to do. I have these three shapes, I want to intersect them all at the end of this function.(One of them appears to have no features, they're just not visible at this scale.)

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
def usable(gdf, feature_gdf, zoom_level, shuffle_tiles=False):

    feature_gdf = gpd.read_file(inshp)
    feature_gdf = feature_gdf.to_crs(epsg=5070)   
    intermediate_result = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
  
    for index, row in gdf.iterrows(): 
        geometry = row['geometry']
        tiles = list_tiles(geometry, zoom=zoom_level, shuf=shuffle_tiles)
         
        for tile in tiles:
            tile_bounds = mercantile.bounds(*tile)
            tile_box = gpd.GeoSeries([box(*tile_bounds)], crs=gdf.crs)
            tile_box = tile_box.to_crs(epsg=5070)       
                 
            if feature_gdf.intersects(tile_box.unary_union).any():
                intersected_features = feature_gdf[feature_gdf.intersects(tile_box.unary_union)]
                buffered_features = intersected_features.copy()
                buffered_features['geometry'] = buffered_features.buffer(buffer_distance)
                tile_minus_buffered = tile_box.difference(buffered_features.unary_union)
                tile_buffer = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=tile_minus_buffered, crs=tile_box.crs)
                intermediate_result = pd.concat([intermediate_result, tile_buffer], ignore_index=True)
                
            else:
                tile_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=tile_box, crs=tile_box.crs)
                intermediate_result = pd.concat([intermediate_result, tile_gdf], ignore_index=True)

        # save_file(intermediate_result, 'result')
    
    dissolved_result = intermediate_result.dissolve()
    
    final_result = gpd.GeoDataFrame()

    for index, row in dissolved_result.iterrows():
        result = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[row['geometry']], crs=dissolved_result.crs)   
        final_result = gpd.overlay(final_result, result, how='intersection')
    print(final_result.head())


Error (from final for-loop):


AttributeError: The CRS attribute of a GeoDataFrame without an active geometry column is not defined. Use GeoDataFrame.set_geometry to set the active geometry column.
```

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do. Can you add some screenshots or drawings to make it clearer?

Comment: BERA - Certainly, I added some links. I don't have enough reputation yet to embed them inline. I am trying to iteratively intersect the three images, though the final product will have an arbitrary number of shapes to intersect. Does that help?

Comment: Do you have only one dataframe and want to find the common intersection of all features in it?

Comment: No, I have three output dataframes (each one is represented in the pictures above) and I want to intersect all three. I understand it will have to be two at a time, since that's how geopandas.overlay works. I'm just struggling with how best to implement that.

Comment: @BERA - Thanks for your patience. This was very helpful! I had to change the 'how' to 'how='intersection'' and now I get the results I was looking for. Do you have any insight into how to use this process for an arbitrary number of dfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to union all frames, then select:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from functools import reduce

df = gpd.read_file(filename=r"C:/GIS/GIStest/10k_buffered_points.geojson")
df["id1"] = 1 #A temp id column
df2 = gpd.read_file(filename=r"C:/GIS/GIStest/swamp.gpkg")
df2["id2"] = 1
df3 = gpd.read_file(filename=r"C:/GIS/GIStest/open_ground.gpkg")
df3["id3"] = 1

unioned = reduce(lambda frame1, frame2: gpd.overlay(df1=frame1, df2=frame2, how="union", keep_geom_type=True),
           [df, df2, df3]) #Union df1+df2, then union the output with df3.

# unioned[["id1","id2","id3"]].sample(3)
#   id1  id2  id3
#   1.0  NaN  1.0       #df1 and df3 intersecting
#   1.0  NaN  NaN       #Only features from df1
#   1.0  1.0  NaN       #df1 and df2 intersecting

intersecting = unioned.loc[unioned[["id1","id2","id3"]].sum(axis=1)>1] #Select rows where two frames intersects (rowwise sum >1)
intersecting.to_file(r"C:/GIS/GIStest/intersecting.gpkg")
```

You might want to dissolve the results.

[image]